# Linked List Word Frequency and Sort C++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, word-frequency, word-cloud

I am writing a program that reads words from a text file and puts all those words in a linked list.  The file has no punctuation, only words.  I also want to compare the linked list to a pre-loaded blacklist that is also a linked list.

What I have accomplished is that I can load the link list from file, print the link list, check the size, count the frequency of how many times a word appeared in the file, not print the words that are below a specified frequency, and I have also been able to format all the words to lowercase for better handling.

What I am having a problem with is getting the code right so that it only prints an occurrence of a word once that has multiple frequencies. So if the word "the" shows up 20 times, I don't want it to print "the <1>" then "the <2>" the next time it shows up, clear to "the <20>" I just want it to print one time "the <20>"

I am posting my load file function, print functions and insert word functions, all part of the `class wordCloud()`.

Below is the code:

```
void wordCloud::insertWord(string aWord){
wordNode *newWord = new wordNode(aWord);

//old code
if (head == NULL)
    head = newWord;
else{
    newWord->next = head;
    head = newWord;
}

//revised code
//newWord->next = head;
//head = newWord;
size++;
}

void wordCloud::insertWordDistinct(string word){
for (wordNode *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next){
    if (word == temp->myWord){
        temp->freq_count++;
        //cout << temp->freq_count; //for debugging
    }
}
insertWord(word);
}

void wordCloud::printWordCloud(int freq){
wordNode *temp, *previous;
int listSize = 0;

if (head == NULL)                   //determines if there are any words in the list
    cout << "No Word Cloud" << endl;
else{
    temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL){         //prints each word until the list is NULL
        if (temp->freq_count >= freq){
            cout << temp->myWord << " <" << temp->freq_count << ">" << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
            listSize++;
        }
        else{
            previous = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            previous = NULL;
            free(previous);
        }
    }
}
cout << "\nThere are " << size << " words in the file.\n";      //print file size - for debugging - works
cout << "\nThere are " << listSize << " words in the list\n\n";     //print list size - for debugging - works
system("pause");
}

void wordCloud::printBlacklist(){
wordNode *temp;

if (head == NULL)                   //determines if there is a list
    cout << "No Words in the blacklist" << endl;
else{
    temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL){           //prints each word until the list is NULL
        cout << temp->myWord << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
cout << "\nThere are " << size << " words in the file.\n\n";        //print size - for debugging - works
system("pause");
}

void wordCloud::loadWordCloud(string fileName){
ifstream file;                      //variable for fileName
string word;                        //string to hold each word

file.open(fileName);                //open file

if (!file) {                        //error handling
    cout << "Error: Can't open the file. File may not exist.\n";
    exit(1);
}

while (!file.eof()){
    file >> word;                   //grab a word from the file one at a time

    insertWordDistinct(changeToLowerCase(word));
    //insertWord(word);             //for debugging
    //cout << word <<'\n';          //print word - for debugging
}

//printWordCloud();                 //print word cloud - for debugging - works
file.close();                       //always make sure to close file after read
}

void wordCloud::loadBlacklist(string fileName){
ifstream file;                      //variable for fileName
string bannedWord;                  //string to hold each word  

file.open(fileName);                //open file

if (!file) {                        //error handling if file does not load
    cout << "Error: Can't open the file. File may not exist.\n";
    exit(1);
}   

while (!file.eof()){
    file >> bannedWord;             //grab a word from the file one at a time

    if (bannedWord.empty()){        //error handling if file is empty
        cout << "File is empty!!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    insertWord(changeToLowerCase(bannedWord));
    //cout << bannedWord << '\n';   //print blacklist words - for debugging
}

//printBlacklist();                 //print blacklist - for debugging - works
file.close();                       //always make sure to close file after read
}
```

I notice that if I put `previous = NULL` before `free()`, that my program does not crash and I don't get any dll memory handling errors.  In fact, I can take `free()` out totally and it seems to work just fine. I just don't know if this is the correct way to do this at all. It seems to me that if I just point a node to NULL< that it won't necessarily delete the data in memory.  I just get uneasy not using `free()` or `delete()` to terminate the node. Correct me if I am wrong, or please point me in the right directly.

Pretty much, what is wrong with this:

```
wordNode *previous, *temp = head;

while (temp != NULL){
    if (word == temp->myWord){
        temp->freq_count++;
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        delete(previous);
    }
}
```

I may be going about this wrong, but basically I just need to find the frequency of each word that is inserted into the list, then delete the multiple nodes that contain that word until only the node with the highest frequency count is left to print. I am trying to do this in `insertWordDistinct(string word)` to accomplish this. Just not sure how to do it.

Comment: That's a biiig description!

Comment: "I started using free() because `delete()` was also giving me memory handling issues" - there is simply no way to describe how **red** that flag is. If you have no `malloc()` you have no need for `free()` (and you have no need for `malloc()`, so *neither* should be in this code whatsoever). And you may as well say right now whether this is for academia vs. not, as it will help stave off a blizzard of ensuing "you're using the wrong container" comments.

Comment: 230 LOC is *not* an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please edit your question to make this easier to answer.

Comment: Regarding sorting your words and calculating frequencies, if the full faith and credit of the standard library is available to you, [I strongly advise you use it](https://ideone.com/HhUDTn).

Comment: @Johnsyweb - I posted all my code, because honestly, I don't know exactly where all my errors are that are causing my program to crash on memory errors.  I tried debugging, but I end up breaking at different points in my code that don't even make sense to me as to what the problem could be.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Yes, this is academia, however I have already missed the deadline to turn this in over a week ago, so I am more so trying to complete this project for my own education now.  I have no idea what your comments mean by the way. I don't know what 'malloc()' is, so I guess I will look that up.  I don't really know why this is "red flag." So if you could explain this in detail, that would be great.

Comment: Also, yes, I can use the standard library and, but I really don't know how that helps me with sort and calculating frequencies. I don't know the library like the back of my hand. So if you could elaborate on that too, I would appreciate it. I checked out your example, but I have to use linked lists, I can't use vectors. You solution looks simple, but at the same time, I have a hard time following it.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I will look an insertion-sort. I will revise my question in a bit to reflect what the most important thing I need help with is, which is deleting multiple words when the frequency is more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print loop is doing you no favors at all. It should be a simple enumeration filtering on minimum frequency. no deleting, freeing, or otherwise memory management should be happening. Just walk the list:

```
void wordCloud::printWordCloud(int freq)
{
    int listSize = 0;
    int uniqSize = 0;
    for (wordNode *temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next)
    {
        if (temp->freq_count >= freq)
        {
            cout << temp->myWord << " <" << temp->freq_count << ">" << endl;
            listSize += temp->freq_count;
            ++uniqSize;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nThere are " << size << " words in the file.\n";
    cout << "\nThere are " << listSize << " words in the filtered list\n\n";
    cout << "\nThere are " << uniqSize << " unique words in the filtered list\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

This should also get you back to properly managing your lists in the `wordCloud::~wordCloud()` destructor to once again properly delete nodes. there are plenty of other things I would do different, but its a learning process so I'm not going to spoil your party.

---

**Update**

Per request from the OP, below is a sample linked list insertion function that insertion sorts as it builds the list. While adapting this he identified significant differences and problems with the original implementation. Hopefully it helps someone else as well.

```
void wordCloud::insert(const std::string& aWord, unsigned int freq)
{
    // manufacture lower-case version of word;
    std::string lcaseWord = make_lower(aWord);

    // search for the word by walking a pointer-to-pointer
    //  through the pointers in the linked list.
    wordNode** pp = &head;
    while (*pp && ((*pp)->myWord < lcaseWord)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (*pp && !(lcaseWord < (*pp)->myWord))
    {
        (*pp)->freq_count++;
    }
    else
    {    // insert the node
        wordNode *node = new wordNode(lcaseWord);
        node->freq_count = freq;
        node->next = *pp;
        *pp = node;
        ++size;
    }
}
```

Comment: So it is my destructor, combined with the bad code in my `printWordCloud()`, that is giving me memory problems you think?  Alright, I will look further into it.  I also see that the listSize is now in the thousands, which means it is just adding up all the frequency counts.  That should probably be fixed when I figure out how to delete the extra words in the list I am guessing.

Comment: @CharlWillia6 The `listSize` in the above code is the number of words (including duplicates) I.e. its the total word count given the frequency constraint. The **uniqSize** is the number of unique words in the resulting list, and probably the value you're looking for.

Comment: The `listSize` is now giving me numbers in the thousand.  So what it is doing is adding up the frequency count, so everytime "the <1>" and then "the <2>", clear up to "the <30>" gets printed, it adds all those frequency counts together. I can't seem to figure out how to only print "the" once from the list. Actually, better yet, I want all the other "the"'s to be deleted from the list, except for the last one with the biggest freq_count.  But `listSize` is now in the thousands, when there is only 472 words in the file. `listSize` would be correct if it didn't print all occurrences of the words.

Comment: @CharlWillia6 Then there is a problem with your insertion code. Perhaps I'm missing what you're trying to do. When you read a file do you want *every* word in the resulting linked list, duplicates included? Or just one instance of every word with an attached frequency count? I ask because `insertWord` blindly throws the word on the end of the list, while `insertDistinctWord` seems to be at least trying to do the latter.

Comment: @CharlWillia6 And just for something different to peruse, [you may find this interesting](http://pastebin.com/X1pfjALr).

Comment: I will take a look and study it. But yes, when I read the file I DO NOT want duplicate words in the list, only one instance of word with the frequency of how many times the word occurred in the file that was read, in this format: the <5>, newline, word <7>, newline...etc.  `insertWord` is a separate function to just do what you said, blindly throw the word in there, while `insertDistinctWord` is supposed to be more in charge of whether or not the word gets to `insertWord` by checking if the word already occurred and increment the freq_count.

Comment: I know my insertDistinctWord is not correct. That is more so why I posted this question is to find out how to get it working, and why I am having unhandled memory when I try to delete nodes, in which is what I was trying to do when creating the list.

Comment: I tried adapting insert function to my code, which I was successful, however I see that when I print the list it is already sorted by descending alphabetical order.  I cannot seem to figure out what in the code does this. Is this in the `transform()` function? It didn't sort it before when I used it in my print function. I was just wondering, because I need to be able to sort this later by frequency count (either ascending or descending, dependent upon a 'A' or 'D' argument).  Thanks. Oh, and you can also post your insert function as the answer to this question and I will set it.

Comment: @Look at the loop in the insert code. Insertion walks forward in the list until discovering something "not greater" than the incoming word. The code that does it is: `while (*pp && (lcaseWord < (*pp)->myWord))`. Now that I look at that i got the order incorrect. It should be `(*pp && ((*pp)->myWord < lcaseWord))`. Duh. If you flip that they will insert in ascending order (which I intended; like I said, never tested =P). The version posted above has it correctly *ascending*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time you did into answering my question and making sure the code works.  I appreciate the help.  While I wasn't looking for something that thorough, it did help me implement some things I had wrong. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to print only one time every word you must make a unique list that will have words from your original list with number of appearances of them. To do this you just need two loops. One for getting every words from original list and second to check if word is in unique list. For this you should make a second list and copy every word once, if word occurs more than once you just increment frequency.